Random generation of Hermitian matrices
I have developed an algorithm to generate normalized Hermitian matrices, given the dimension N, the maximum number of non-zero elements in each column d, and the condition number k, that is, the 2-norm of the inverse of the generated matrix.
I would like to test if this algorithm is truly random, that is if it is equivalent to a uniform distribution with as values normalized Hermitian matrices with N, d, k fixed. How to perform this test? I know about the KS test, but it can be applied only to multivariate continuous distributions, which isn't the case.
The algorithm proceeds as following:

Randomly choose $N_U$ $b_i \in [1,d]$ such that $\sum_{i = 1}^{N_U} b_i = N$ and $b_j = d$ for at least one $j$, where $N_U$ will depend on the choice of the $b_i$.
Generate $U_i$ random unitary matrices for $i = 1, ..., N_U$, each of dimension $b_i \times b_i$.
Join all the $U_i$ in a diagonal block matrix U.
Generate a random diagonal matrix $D = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_N)$, such that there exist $\lambda_{max} = 1$ and $\lambda_{min} = 1/k$, and $\lambda_{min} < \lambda_i < \lambda_{max}$, to ensure that the condition number of the final matrix is $k$.
Then, $H = U  D  U^\dagger$ will be a Hermitian matrix with condition number $k$ and maximum $d$ non-zero values in each row.
Apply a random permutation to $H$.

Note that the normalization is guaranteed by the algorithm.

can you specify the sampling set of the ENTRIES of the matrix and the distribution that each non-zero element is supposed to be draw from? Hermitian is just the condition $AA^{\dagger} = I$ and doesn't necessarily tell us how you're sampling these matrices. If your entries are integers from $0$ to $100$ versus real numbers from $[0,1]$ this may result in very different kinds of tests

@SidharthGhoshal Updated.
